# JSF - Update model values from view before validation

Tags: java, jsf, lifecycle

I have one form with several components, some of them have their own validations and/or are mandatory. Then I also have several `selectOneMenu` components that have the same three `selectItem` elements in their lists. I have defined three `commandButton` in order to select the same values for all the lists (one `commandButton` per possible value).

**The JSF section**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h:outputText value="ID:" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <h:inputText value="#{MyClass.id}" id="inTxt_id" required="true">
                <f:validator validatorId="CheckIDPattern" />
            </h:inpuText>
            <h:message for="inTxt_id" errorClass="error" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h:commandButton value="Select all opt1" action="#{MyClass.selectOpt1}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Select all opt2" action="#{MyClass.selectOpt2}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Select all opt3" action="#{MyClass.selectOpt3}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h:outputText value="List 1:" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{MyClass.list1Val}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{MyClass.listOfOptions}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h:outputText value="List 2:" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{MyClass.list2Val}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{MyClass.listOfOptions}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         //Many other selectOneMenu components...
    </tr>
</table>
<h:commandButton action="#{MyClass.saveLists}" value="Submit" />
```

**MyClass.java**

```
public String selectOpt1(){
    this.list1Val = 1;
    this.list2Val = 1;
    //...
    return "";
}

//The same idea for selectOpt2 and selectOpt3.
```

In this context, if my user presses one of my "select all" buttons without filling the ID `inputText`, it receives the error message, but I don't want it because I suppose they haven't finished filling the form. I just want the validations to be executed when the user presses the "Save Lists" button.

I've tried adding `immediate="true"` to my "select all" buttons, it works but it doesn't update the view from model and then the user doesn't see the values have changed... so it really doesn't work.

**What do I want to achieve?** I just want the validations to be performed when the last button (submit). So my user could use these "select all" buttons without filling previously the mandatory components.

I hope you understand my context. Feel free to ask for any clarification.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `@ViewScoped` bean you could do the following changes:

First change your `selectOpt1` method to type `void`:

```
public void selectOpt1() 
{
    this.list1Val = 1;
    this.list2Val = 1;
    //...
}
```

Give an `id` to the component you want to update upon selecting items. I assume List 1 in this case:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="list1" value="#{MyClass.list1Val}">
    //...
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

And in your button, add an `f:ajax` tag that partially submits only that component for processing:

```
<h:commandButton value="Select all opt1" action="#{MyClass.selectOpt1}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="list1" />
</h:commandButton>
```

If you plan to update multiple components, you may add their id separated by space:

```
<f:ajax execute="@this" render="list1 list2" />
```

I hope it helps.

**Edit**

Well, sorry, I didn't noticed you're using JSF 1.x. In this case it wouldn't work.

You could use a library such as [RichFaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) to add ajax functionality though. Please, check out these topics:

- [ajax behaviour in jsf 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715731/ajax-behaviour-in-jsf-1-2)
- [how do i call a jsf action method (in JSF 1.2) using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545539/how-do-i-call-a-jsf-action-method-in-jsf-1-2-using-ajax)

**RichFaces**

As you mentioned you're using RichFaces you could switch the `f:ajax` tag to `a4j:support`:

```
<h:commandButton value="Select all opt1" action="#{MyClass.selectOpt1}">
    <a4j:support event="onclick" reRender=":list1" ajaxSingle="true" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Or like this using the `a4j:commandButton`:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Select all opt1" reRender=":list1" ajaxSingle="true" />
```

For more info on this behavior, please take a look at [this](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#d0e1166).

Regards.

Comment: hmmm... The bean is session scoped, but i'm working on **JSF 1.2** (for some reasons I've been unable to migrate to JSF 2.0 :(). Can this solution be adapted to my JSF version? Thanks!

Comment: Well, this wouldn't work for JSF 1.x. One option would be using a library such as RichFaces as this add ajax functionality. I've used it in the past and it's kind of easy to get started. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It definetly was my fault, I didn't specify what technology I was using. And yes, I also use RichFaces and I work with `a4j:support`, but I can't solve the problem properly. Thank you for the related topic, I will study it.

Comment: @jmrodrigg No problem. Partially updating components in a page is truly ajax territory. See my edit and good luck. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've found solution that works using `a4j:commandButton`. In few minutes I'll write an answer specifying the changes I've included to make it work. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @jmrodrigg Glad it worked. Did you see my `a4j:commandButton`edit?

Answer (score 2):

Just let the `required` attribute depend on the button pressed.

```html
<h:form id="form">
    <c:set var="saveButtonPressed" value="#{not empty param['form:save']}" />
    ...
    <h:inputText ... required="#{saveButtonPressed}" />
    ...
    <h:commandButton id="save" ... />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thank you for this different approach. I didn't know that was possible. Althought `a4j:commandButton` suits better for my purpose, it's nice to know different solutions. Thank you!

Comment: @BalusC THX many many times! I've spent hours searching for such a solution!

Answer (score 0):

After taking into account **Bento**'s advices, i realitzed the only way to make it work as I wanted was using AJAX `a4j`.

The changes I've had to introduce in my code are:

1. Replace `h:commandButton` "select all" buttons with `a4j:commandButton`.
2. Define `id` tags for my `h:selectOneMenu` components, so I could *reRender* the components through `a4j:commandButton` defined before.

The **JSF** original page has been modified as follows:

```
(...)
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a4j:commandButton value="Select all opt1" action="#{MyClass.selectOpt1}"
                reRender="list1,list2,(...)" ajaxSingle="true" />
            <a4j:commandButton value="Select all opt2" action="#{MyClass.selectOpt2}"
                reRender="list1,list2,(...)" ajaxSingle="true" />
            <a4j:commandButton value="Select all opt3" action="#{MyClass.selectOpt3}"
                reRender="list1,list2,(...)" ajaxSingle="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h:outputText value="List 1:" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{MyClass.list1Val}" id="list1">
                <f:selectItems value="#{MyClass.listOfOptions}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h:outputText value="List 2:" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{MyClass.list2Val}" id="list2">
                <f:selectItems value="#{MyClass.listOfOptions}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </td>
    </tr>
(...)
```

Thanks a lot **Bento** for your advices!